# Override Grails service bean definition with plugin

Tags: grails

I want to override a service implementation by just installing a plugin - when the plugin is installed I want the plugin-version of the service to be used and when the plugin is uninstalled I want the default version of the service to be used.

To prevent wasting time, I'll explain my problem using code. I have a "common plugin" that is shared by my main application and my "custom plugin" with the following:

```
public interface SimpleService {
    void doProcessing();
}
```

I then have a "main application" that contains the following

Default implementation of service interface:

```
public DefaultSimpleService implements SimpleService {
    void doProcessing() {
        // ...
    }
```

resource.groovy:

```
simpleService(DefaultSimpleService) { bean ->
    bean.autowire = 'byName'
}
```

Controller that uses the service:

```
class SimpleController {
    def simpleService

    def index() {
        simpleService.doProcessing()
    }
}
```

So far so good. What I now want to do is to replace the implementation of `SimpleService` interface with a new one by just installing a plugin. I do not want to change any configuration within my application.

I have a plugin with a new implementation of the service:

```
public CustomSimpleService implements SimpleService {
    void doProcessing() {
        // ...
    }
}
```

My first attempt was to register the custom service bean in the plugins "doWithSpring" section, but it is always overridden by the main application. Fair enough since it seems like plugins are always loaded before main application beans is registered (?)

My second attempt was to register the custom bean in "doWithApplicationContext" inside my CustomServiceGrailsPlugin.groovy:

```
def doWithApplicationContext = { applicationContext ->
    DefaultListableBeanFactory beanFactory = (DefaultListableBeanFactory) applicationContext.getBeanFactory()
    beanFactory.registerBeanDefinition("simpleService", BeanDefinitionBuilder.rootBeanDefinition(CustomSimpleService.class.getName()).getBeanDefinition())
}
```

This actually works partially - When the plugin is loaded the plugins implementation of SimpleService is used, and if the plugin is uninstalled the main applications implementation of `SimpleService` is used. But there was a side issue: autowiring of beans is not working inside the plugin implementation that was "manually" registered...

Then I started to look at `BeanPostProcessors` but from what I read it looked like it wouldn't solve my problem.

So how do I solve my problem?

Regards
Tobbe

Comment: How is that supposed to work?  Plugins can't make static reference to classes defined by the host application, so `public CustomSimpleService implements SimpleService` shouldn't compile...  And you are correct that beans defined by the main application override those defined by plugins, that is how it is supposed to work.

Comment: well.. it was a simplification, in the real world the interface definition resides in yet another plugin that is imported by both main application and the "custom plugin". But any idea how i could override the implementation? except for registerBeanDefinition (which doesnt include autowiring)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that your best bet is to check if the plugin is installed and don't declare the service in the application if so.

You can check the plugins installed with: `org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.PluginManagerHolder.pluginManager.allPlugins`

And you can use this in the resources.groovy

```
boolean containsPlugin(String pluginName) {
    def names = org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.PluginManagerHolder.pluginManager.allPlugins.collect { it -> return it.name }  
    return(pluginName in names) 
}


beans = {
  if(!containsPlugin("thePlugin")) {
    println "Installation not contains plugin, defining bean!"
    myService(...)
  }
}
```

Comment: OP wants a _custom plugin_ definition of a particular bean to take precedence over a definition of the same bean name in the _host app_, not in the common plugin.

Comment: I guess this is as good as it gets (so i mark it as an answer), i dont like having the plugin name in the code but if i go this way i will move it to config at least. Thanks alot for taking the time!